# Integrating PaySimple into a PHP website

Tags: php, payment-processing

I want to integrate the [PaySimple API](http://www.paysimple.com/) on my website, but I don't have any guide for this.

My website is in php; are there any documents or guides for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PaySimple Developer Portal is here:
http://developer.paysimple.com/

The PaySimple API Documentation is here:
http://developer.paysimple.com/documentation/

Comment: Just wanted to note for future readers that the link above now just redirects to PaySimple's homepage.  I was able to find PaySimple API Documentation at https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com/3.00/help/PaySimple_3.00_APIDeveloperDocumentation.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Rohit
If you have signed up for an account you should have been given the documentation on this link:
https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com/3.00/help/default.html

If not, we strongly encourage you to contact our business team to set one up and at that point we would issue a Sandbox account where you can develop.

PaySimple cannot provide you with PHP code samples, however our support link posted in [Warren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507917/paysimple-in-php-code/4508176#4508176) may guide you regarding business rules and the structure you wish to establish.  The link posted here will provide you with our API objects and their methods.

If you can replicate the example calls then you should be well on your way to processing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Pay Simple representative I just got off the phone with, Pay Simple doesn't have an API that they make available. When I pointed to the documentation that is available online they said that the documentation was there, but that there did not give anyone api keys to use it.

So at least according to the person I spoke with, you can't integrate with PaySimple directly using PHP. You *can* take payments using their webforms, but that isn't really an api level integration.